# How can I set my event's 'status' attribute to 'live' using Eventbrite's API?

Tags: api, eventbrite

I am doing Eventbrite integration in my Application. I am trying to create Event and make it live. I found the Event creation API, but that doesn't include any information on how to make the even live.

How can I set my event's 'status' attribute to 'live' using Eventbrite's API?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using one of the [Eventbrite API clients](http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/libraries/), you should be able to do something like this:

```
eb_client.event_update({id: event_id, status: 'live'});
```

I'd recommend trying the interactive documentation page for the [event_update API call](http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/events/event_update/) to learn more.

The developer site uses our available [OAuth2.0](http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/authentication/oauth2/) authorization service to access your events, allowing you to inspect your API request urls and response data.

Before you go live, make sure that your event has [tickets](http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/tickets/) available, and that you have assigned a [venue](http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/venues/) and [organizer profile](http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/organizers/) whenever possible.